# Why does thread join behave differently in this example?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, thread-safety

Updated question to be more generic:

I have the following code. When you swap the location of threads[i].Join() you get different output.

```
static void ThreadedWorker(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working from results[ " + startIndex +"] to results["+endIndex+"]");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int threadCount = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
    int calculationCount = 500; //the number of array elements we'd be iterating over if we were doing our work
    int threadDataChunkSize = calculationCount / threadCount;
    if (threadDataChunkSize < 1) threadDataChunkSize = 1; //just in case we have loads of threads

    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new Thread(() => ThreadedWorker(threadDataChunkSize * i, threadDataChunkSize*(i+1)));
        threads[i].Start();
        //threads[i].Join(); //****Uncomment for correct behaviour****
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        //threads[i].Join(); //****Uncomment for incorrect behaviour****
    }

    Console.WriteLine("breakhere");
}
```

When `Join()` is in the first loop, creating sequential behaviour, you get the output

```
Working from results[ 0] to results[125]
Working from results[ 125] to results[250]
Working from results[ 250] to results[375]
Working from results[ 375] to results[500]
```

When `Join()` is in the second loop, creating parallel behaviour, you get non deterministic output something like:

```
Working from results[ 375] to results[500]
Working from results[ 375] to results[500]
Working from results[ 500] to results[625]
Working from results[ 500] to results[625] (i is sometimes more than it should ever be!)
```

My suspicion is that lambda expression somehow causes the problem. Hopefully this rephrasing also demonstrates that this is not a bounds miscalculation, or other abuse of my arrays!

---

Initial question was less generic and used the startIndex and endIndex to iterate over a byte array doing work. I described the `ThreadedWorker` as 'not working', as it seemed to sometimes update the result array and sometimes not. It now appears that it was called but the startindex and endindex were mangled.

Comment: My output array is divided into 8 chunks. The first 1/8 seems never to get filled, while the lower stripes sometimes get filled, sometimes not. It's all or nothing, the chunk in question is either totally correct or totally wrong. This leads me to believe that `ThreadedBlend` is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct, but you're misunderstanding the problem.

Lambda expressions are thread-safe.

However, all of your lambda expressions are sharing the same `i` variable.
Therefore, if one of the threads happens to start after the loop moves on to the next iteration, it will pick up the newer value of `i`.

By declaring a separate variable inside the loop, you're forcing each lambda to use its own variable, which never changes.

Comment: Thank you for wording the problem so much better! This was what I was trying to express, but with no real knowledge of lambda expressions I was unable to describe it in my solution. I am going to go and learn about them now...

Answer (score 5):

The first code `Join`s to each thread right after you start it, before starting the next thread.

Therefore, all of the threads run in sequence.

The second code runs all of the threads immediately, then `Join`s all of them at once.

Therefore, the threads are running concurrently on the exact same data.

The second code probably isn't working because your code or data isn't threadsafe.

Comment: Yep, I know the first one runs in sequence (that's why it's not any use to me!) I should clarify - data contains a start and end point of the data on which to work. An array size t is split up into workSize = `t/NumberOfProcessors` chunks of work which are doled out to each thread. Each thread does work from `workSize*i` to `workSize*(i+1)`. So for array of size 20 on 4 cores, each chunk is size 5, `thread1(0,5)`, `thread2(5,10)`, `thread3(10,15)`, `thread4(15,20)`. [arrays that aren't a multiple of NumberofProcessors are kept safe by a condition check in ThreadedBlend]

Comment: @Bom: No; they all share the same `data`.

Comment: @SLaks I think you know the answer and I don't understand... Sorry if I'm being slow. I know they operate on the same array but I thought it was possible for threads to each to operate on a distinct subdivision of one array at the same time. Is this not possible?  All the threads in my test case are actually doing the same operation loop, filling the array with 128. Is there an implicit lock when accessing an array?

Comment: @Bomadeno: It is possible, but you aren't doing it.  You're passing the same `data` instance to every thread.

Comment: I want to pass the same data instance to every thread. Simple example: one thread fills one half with 128, the other thread fills the other half with 128. My problem is somewhere else. I'm trying to create a more concise example of the problem and will update my question shortly.

Comment: They get the range as shown in my updated question. Can you revise your answer to point people to my answer? The problem wasn't related to bad ranges/misuse of data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

And to finish the update to my question, I got to the bottom of it. As the lambda expression is not thread safe, I need to store i in a temp variable on each loop iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
{
    int temp = i;
    threads[temp] = new Thread(() => ThreadedMultiplier(threadDataChunkSize * temp, threadDataChunkSize * (temp + 1)));
threads[temp].Start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
{
    //threads[i].Join(); //****Uncomment for  correct + parallel behaviour at last!****
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx